# Forking N child processes properly

Tags: c, process, fork

So I am programming a simple rummy card game. I need to create either 3, 4 or 5 processes where the parent acts as the dealer handing the cards to them. I am coming across an unexpected fault I am not sure how to approach.

The output I get is:

```
15019373x-apollo:/home/15019373x/comp2432/lab3$ ./rummy 3
Child: 1 PID 26581
Child: 2 PID 26582
Child: 3 PID 26585
15019373x-apollo:/home/15019373x/comp2432/lab3$ Child: 2 PID 26584
Child: 3 PID 26586
Child: 3 PID 26583
Child: 3 PID 26587
```

So I was trying to create 3 processes but the loop seems to create 7. I'm not too sure what's happening.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int players = atoi(argv[1]);
    char deck[52][3];
    int i, pid, cid;

    if (players > 5 || players < 3)
    {
            printf("%d is not the allowed number of players, min is 3 and max is 5\n", players);
            exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < argc - 2; i++)
    {
            strcpy(deck[i], argv[i+2]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < players; i++)
    {
            pid = fork();
            if (pid < 0)
            {
                    printf("Fork Failed\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
            else if (pid == 0)
            {
                    printf("Child: %d PID %d\n", i+1, getpid());
            }
    }
```

}

If someone could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Each of your child processes are also calling `fork`.

Comment: You put "break/exit" statement  in child block to avoid the calling of fork by child process

Comment: Thank you Pranav, that fixed it!

Comment: That is exactly what I suggested.

Comment: Yes I gave you the answer tick. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the children *also* continue executing the `for` loop and `fork` more children.

As a simple fix (as you are clearly still developing this program), call `exit()` after the `printf` in the child code. You don't want the children to keep executing code that is only intended for the parent to run.

Comment: Oh right I see, but how would I go about this problem :/ Thanks though I get what's happening now.